# Jquery resizable destroy remove handles elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
handles: {
    'nw': '.nw',
    'ne': '.ne',
    'sw': '.sw',
    'se': '.se',
    'n': '.n',
    'e': '.e',
    's': '.s',
    'w': '.w'
},aspectRatio: true

//Button click change resizable aspectRatio to false
$().resizable("destroy").resizable({
    handles: {
        'nw': '.nw',
        'ne': '.ne',
        'sw': '.sw',
        'se': '.se',
        'n': '.n',
        'e': '.e',
        's': '.s',
        'w': '.w'
    },aspectRatio: false

});
```

I have a button click will change resizable aspectRatio to false.

My problem is when I use resizable destroy, it remove all handles element.

anyone know how to update resizable without remove any element?

Comment: Could you please build a jsfiddle showing the issue you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i have searched there is no straight forward way to do this. To achieve this functionality you may need to edit the plugin and add two lines of code in it. You can create a global variable for aspectRatio and tell the code to refer that and do the re-sizing.

search the below code in `jquery-ui.js` file (tested with version 1.11.2)

```
if (this._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey) {
    data = this._updateRatio(data, event);
}
```

and replace it with

```
if(typeof window.globalAspectRatio != "undefined")
    this._aspectRatio = !!(window.globalAspectRatio);

if (this._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey) {
    data = this._updateRatio(data, event);
}
```

Now if the `window.globalAspectRatio` is set and not null then the `aspectRatio` will be true else it ill be false.
You can use it like

```
$('button').click(function(){
    window.globalAspectRatio = !(window.globalAspectRatio);
})
```

Comment: Awesome, Thx a lot! I found the other answer without changeing plugin, it use boolen, http://jsfiddle.net/882k9/

Comment: You do realize that the fiddle is removing and recreating the element right?